# Error about sun/misc/BASE64Encoder on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, base64, eclipse-photon

when i run my app in mac, and show up this message
[image]
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'IMPEXP'.
sun/misc/BASE64Encoder

but this project is work fine in windows 10 computer, and i don't use any about base64Encoder

eclipse Version: Photon Milestone 3 (4.8.0M3)
JRE java se 9.0

edit!

i found something like below

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2017-11-09 11:50:09.047
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SignedJarBuilder.<init>(SignedJarBuilder.java:177)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.init(ApkBuilder.java:446)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:422)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:362)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.finalPackage(BuildHelper.java:391)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.finalDebugPackage(BuildHelper.java:359)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2240)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:120)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:1143)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder cannot be found by com.android.ide.eclipse.base_23.0.7.2120684
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.

Comment: @greg-449 could you explain more ? I don't know how to look .log and .metadata.

Comment: ,metadata is a folder in you workspace. Folders starting with '.' are hidden so Finder won't show them. You can see it in Terminal using the `ls -a` command. Inside .metadata is a file called .log, again this is hidden. Terminal commands such as `less` can display it. You can also use the 'Error Log' view in Eclipse.

Comment: @greg-449 i found something in .log , could you check for me ? thanks!

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/sdklib/src/main/java/com/android/sdklib/internal/build/SignedJarBuilder.java#177

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/316844/132

Answer (score 7):

As others have pointed out already, this is a compatibility issue—you need exactly Java 8 to run Eclipse.

- Install JDK 8 if you don’t have it already.
- In Eclipse, go to **Window > Preferences > Installed JREs**. Make sure Java 8 appears in the list and is selected. After that, close Eclipse.
- Additionally, [`eclipse.ini`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) also has a reference to the Java VM it uses. Make sure the VM it points to is Java 8 (see link on how to find it and how to set VM preferences).
- Restart Eclipse and try again.

Answer (score 3):

The Android code you are using is trying to use the `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` class.

This deprecated class has been removed from Java 9 so this is not going to work.

You will need to switch back to Java 8 or find an update to the Android code (if there is one).

Comment: This is the Java that Eclipse itself is running, **not** the Java your project is using. Eclipse requires at least Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working with Windows 7. I had to change the preferences and the ini file. Both had C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin which I changed to C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\bin. It now works!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was something very crazy.
I have to download the eclipse IDE Version NEON

Since the project is old almost from 2014

Attached the url of the IDE for which you need it:
[Eclipse IDE NEON](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/neon/3/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers)

[image]

I also had to follow the same installation steps