# Eclipse org.eclipse.core.resources java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have  new instalation of Eclipse.
I am trying to debug allready finished android apps.
When I try to launch them I get following responce:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'kvizorama'.
sun/misc/BASE64Encoder
```

I tried to remove Android Package Builder, but error remains the same.
Error log shows this:

```
org.eclipse.core.resources
Error
Sun Apr 19 16:45:49 CEST 2020
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SignedJarBuilder.<init>(SignedJarBuilder.java:177)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.init(ApkBuilder.java:446)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:422)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:362)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.finalPackage(BuildHelper.java:391)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.finalDebugPackage(BuildHelper.java:359)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:832)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2292)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:1143)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:860)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:719)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1017)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$2.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder cannot be found by com.android.ide.eclipse.base_23.0.7.2120684
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:171)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 23 more
```

I tried to read about it, but I cannot find any answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error about sun/misc/BASE64Encoder on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47216694/error-about-sun-misc-base64encoder-on-eclipse)

Comment: Yes, this is the answer I used below, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50164402/5350750
I allready tried to change Java WM, but until I did it manually in eclipse.ini there was no effect.