# Deploy Android app to emulator fails with NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I have the following environment:

Eclipse v4.19.0

Android Development Tools v23.0.7 (Eclipse plugin)

JREs: 8, 7, 6, 5

When I want to deploy test Android application to emulator, I receive following error message:
[image]

Eclipse log:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2021-05-14 18:40:51.825
> !MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
> !STACK 0
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 566 2021-05-14 18:40:51.826
> !MESSAGE Errors occurred during the build.
> !SUBENTRY 1 com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 75 2021-05-14 18:40:51.826
> !MESSAGE Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'First'.
> !STACK 0
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder

Where is the problem? Why it cannot found that class?

Comment: It is trying to use a class that no longer exists in modern versions of Java. Eclipse has not been supported for Android development for a long time now.

Comment: Possible duplicate.
A correct answer might be here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47216694/error-about-sun-misc-base64encoder-on-eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the solution was to install:

JRE 8

Eclipse IDE 2019-06 (v4.12.0)

Android Development Tools v23.0.7.2120684

With the above it works perfectly!

[image]